# How can I get all the values in a radio button group?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button that's in a group, this group has many radio buttons that can go on forever. I want a list of all of the values of the radio buttons.
So if i have a radio button group like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="9" id="q9" required/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="8" id="q8"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="7" id="q7"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="6" id="q6"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="5" id="q5"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="4" id="q4"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="3" id="q3"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="2" id="q2"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="1" id="q1"/>
```

It will return a list of the values like this ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"] in native javascirpt.

Comment: Get a list of all the radio buttons (you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` for this). Convert it to an array. Then use `map()` to get all the values.

Answer (score 1):

Use documentQuerySelector all to get a node list and then iterate over that with a map to get the values into  an array. Note that you will need to spread it to get an iterable and the array will be in  DOM order unless you sort it.

```js
const nameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=name]');
const nameValues = [...nameInputs].map(input => input.value)
console.log(nameValues) ; // gives ["9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"]
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="name" value="9" id="q9" required/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="8" id="q8"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="7" id="q7"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="6" id="q6"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="5" id="q5"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="4" id="q4"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="3" id="q3"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="2" id="q2"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" value="1" id="q1"/>
```